# IsEnabled binding Button and Checkbox

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I've a button and a checkbox.
For both the `IsEnabled` binding is set to the same property:

```
<CheckBox x:Name="CbShowAll"
          Content="Bla"
          IsEnabled="{Binding WaitForRefresh}" />

<Button x:Name="BtnReload"
       Content="Bla"
       IsEnabled="{Binding WaitForRefresh}" />
```

If I change the `WaitForRefresh` property, the button changes its enabled state - the checkbox not. Entering manually "true" or "false" to `IsEnabled` for the checkbox, everything work as expected.

Comment: are you 100% sure? disabled CheckBox looks pretty like enabled one in wpf default theme

Comment: I'm sure ... the button is disabled (gray) and cannot be clicked while I can change the checkbox's checking ... setting the IsEnabled="false" does exactly what I want ... but without binding.

Comment: It looks strange. Any binding errors?

Comment: Some other part of code set the IsEnabled "by hand" ... damn ... Question can be closed/deleted.

Comment: Try debugging the code to find the statement setting the IsEnabled Property

Answer (score -2):

Try doing something like this

```
IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=ApplicationWindow, Path=WaitForRefresh}"
```

where ElementName is name of your WPF window.